# Asking for birthday as a user input without using java.util.Date method

Tags: java, oop, user-input

I am trying to make a program that will allow the user to input two sets of name and birthday and will compare whether the inputs are identical.

I have a separate class named MyDate which contains the month, day and year, thus I created an object which I named "dob" in my person class, which contains the String name and MyDate dob . Upon creating a test program, I'm having difficulty on how to get the birthday input and set it as "MM-dd-yyyy" since I cannot use the java.util.Date method.

This is what I have so far:

```
    System.out.println("Enter birthdate: ");
    String bd=console.next();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    MyDate dob = sdf.parse(bd);
    p1.setDob(dob);
```

Any idea on how to fix it? any help would be appreciated

class MyDate for this program:

```
public class MyDate {
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;
    
    public MyDate() {
    }
    
    public MyDate(int month, int day, int year) {
        setDay(month);
        setMonth(day);
        setYear(year);
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.getMonth() ^ this.getDay() ^ this.getYear();
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.month+"-"+this.day+"-"+this.year+" ";
    }
    
}
```

The program's output should look similar to this:

```
    enter name: jay
    enter birthday: 02-07-1999
    enter name: jay
    enter birthday: 02-07-1999
    IDENTICAL
    name: jay
    birthday: 02-07-1999
    name: jay
    birthday: 02-07-1999
```

Comment: Please update the answer with the Mydate details as well.

Comment: We can't help you with your difficulty if we can't see the code you're having difficulties with.

Comment: For starters, if you don't specify to the user how you want the input to be formatted, the user most likely enter it incorrectly. You can prompt the user "Enter birthday in the following format: MM-dd-yyyy"

Comment: Or you can collect the input over several prompts. For example "Enter two digits for your birthday month:" followed by "Enter two digits for your the day" etc.

Comment: lets say I created several prompts, but how would I make the output appear as MM-dd-yyyy?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` does not have a method for converting to your `MyDate` object, you need to build this functionality yourself. For example you should be using the constructor `MyDate dob = new MyDate(month, day, year);` and using the correct values when constructing the object. As for how to display it correctly, your toString method looks fine to me.

Comment: @rave I think my answer answered your original question and also the one you posted in the comments about how to make the output appear as MM-dd-YYYY. If I did, don't forget to mark my answer as the accepted answer. ;)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. If allowed use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also is designing your own `MyDate` class is a requirement, it’s a fine exercise; in production code one would always use `LocalDate` instead.

Comment: @OleV.V. The OP stated "_I cannot use the java.util.Date_". I am sure that extends to other Standard Library classes as well. I have a feeling this is a homework where students need to implement their own solutions.

Comment: @hfontanez That was my feeling too, though I cannot know. Many other readers are probably in a different situation.

Comment: @OleV.V. that's why I almost always upvote OP questions that clearly indicate "this is a homework" regardless of the quality of the question. That piece of info alone frames the question very good in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you cannot do this `MyDate dob = sdf.parse(bd);` According to the Java doc, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html, SimpleDateformat parse method returns Date object while your dob has MyDate. you cant mix both type.

What you want to do is to take the input from the user and pass it to your MyDate constructor. I have a follow up question, since you are not allowed to use Java.util.Date, are you allowed to use the SimpleDateFormat given that the parse return Date?

Assuming that your program is a simple program and advance validation is not required, you can use split by - on the input which will give you an array of 3 items and you can pass them to MyDate based on the index.

In order to do identical check, you will need to override the Equals method in your Person class

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution

```
System.out.print("Enter birthdate in the following format MM-dd-YYYY: ");
String bd=console.next();
```

That might not be as good as the following solution:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number your birthdate month (i.e. 1 for January) : ");
int mm = console.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter your birth day : ");
int dd = console.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the four digits of your birthdate year: ");
int yyyy = console.nextInt();
console.close();
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append(String.format("%02d", mm));
buffer.append("-");
buffer.append(String.format("%02d", dd));
buffer.append("-");
buffer.append(String.format("%04d", yyyy));
String date = buffer.toString();
System.out.println(date);
```

This is more verbose, but I think it is a better solution than the first one. The result:

```
Enter the number your birthdate month (i.e. 1 for January) : 
7
Enter your birth day : 
10
Enter the four digits of your birthdate year: 
1968
07-10-1968
```

The above solution can be transformed into what the OP wants very easily.

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number your birthdate month (i.e. 1 for January) : ");
int mm = console.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter your birth day : ");
int dd = console.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the four digits of your birthdate year: ");
int yyyy = console.nextInt();
console.close();
MyDate dob = new MyDate(mm, dd, yyyy);
```

The `MyDate` class should be modified with the rest of my original code as follows:

```
public class MyDate {
// rest of code omitted
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        buffer.append(String.format("%02d", mm));
        buffer.append("-");
        buffer.append(String.format("%02d", dd));
        buffer.append("-");
        buffer.append(String.format("%04d", yyyy));
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

**SUPPLEMENTAL INFO**:

I stated that I believe it was easier to capture the *month*, *day*, and *year* in separate prompts rather than all at once. Of course, this is a matter of opinion. However, for cases where it is required to capture the input all at once, I never completed the code in the `MyDate` class. For starters, you'll need to validate the string by analyzing its pattern:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter your birthdate (MM-dd-YYYY): ");
        input =  scanner.next();
    } while (!input.matches("\\d{1,2}-?\\d{1,2}-?\\d{4}"));
}
System.out.println("input matched! " + input);
```

This snippet will continue to prompt until the input is validated:

```
Enter your birthdate (MM-dd-YYYY): foo
Enter your birthdate (MM-dd-YYYY): MM-dd-YYYY
Enter your birthdate (MM-dd-YYYY): 7-10-1968
input matched! 7-10-1968
```

Once you have a valid match, you can either set the string as a whole in the `MyDate` class, but I also suggest to break down the String into its components (*month*, *day*, and *year*), so that your class can provide meaningful data based on the date entered.

```
public class MyDate {
    private String date;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;

    public MyDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
        String[] tokens = date.split("-");
        month = tokens[0];
        day = tokens[1];
        year = tokens[2];
    }
// getter and setters omitted
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return date; // since it was validated by the provider, no extra processing is required
    }
}
```

Aside from regular setter and getter methods, and regardless of solution (one vs. multiple prompts), your `MyDate` class should also provide specialized methods to get, for instance, a month as a name rather than as a number.

```
public String getMonthName() {
    switch (month) {
        case 1: return "January";
        case 2: return "February";
        ...
    }
}
```

Another form of validation you need to do, probably in the constructor is to make sure the numeric values for day and month are correct. For example, month can only be values 1-12. If inputted value is outside that range, you need to throw some sort of exception. Likewise, if the value of days is incorrect, you need to throw some sort of exception. Also, days need to be validated based on month and year in the case of February (leap year). I won't add code for that. You can "google" that information and add it to your `MyDate` implementation.